# Rest POST not working in CRON task(it works with manual rake command)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, cron

So, I have an app that works with the Whenever Gem to execute scheduled tasks. And then, I have a task that do a post request with RestClient, and it works fine when I execute it by myself with a "rake" on terminal. But when the task is execute through cron jobs, it doesn't work. The post request looks like this:

```
    urlOAuth = ENV['URL_AUTH']
    client_id = ENV['CLIENT_ID']
    client_secret = ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']

    data = {
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      scope: 'read-data',
      client_id: client_id,
      client_secret: client_secret
    }

    result = RestClient.post(urlOAuth, data)
```

As I said, when executing this task with a manual rake command, it works fine. When the task is executed by cronjob, it returns this error:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: must pass :url
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:79:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:63:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:63:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient.rb:70:in `post'
/root/micro-app-api-idfm/lib/tasks/get_send_json.rake:22:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

So, I tried passing the url directly in the task code, still got an error:

```
rake aborted!
RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:249:in `exception_with_response'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:129:in `return!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:836:in `process_result'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:743:in `block in transmit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:727:in `transmit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:163:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:63:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rest-client-2.1.0/lib/restclient.rb:70:in `post'
/root/micro-app-api-idfm/lib/tasks/get_send_json.rake:22:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

What should I do? No idea why this is not working since it works fine with a manual rake command. I'd appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Edit¹.:

I tried raising an exception to check specifically what is happening with this 400 Bad Request. And here is what I got:

```
 { 
    "error" : "invalid_client",
    "error_description" : "Client authentication failed (e.g. unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method). The authorization server MAY return an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code to indicate which HTTP authentication schemes are supported. "
  }
rake aborted!
```

Which still doesn't make sense, since it's working when the task is executed manually, so the client should be valid

Comment: Added details on the post directly, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @anothermh I managed to find out that the cron was not accessing the ENV variables for whatever reason, still didn't find out why.

But, since I'm using `dotenv` gem, what did workout was using its own syntax for tasks(I didn't have to do that before, but now I do, no idea why yet). Which is doing something like this at the beginning of every task, to make sure the .env file is being "manually" loaded:

```
require 'dotenv/tasks'

task mytask: :dotenv do
    # things that require .env
end
```

You can check for more in the own dotenv github page. Thank you for those who tried to help!
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Answer (score 1):

The user running the rake task doesn't have the environment variables set in `ENV`. That's why you get a different error (400 Bad Request) when you pass in the URL directly.

In the first case there are no `ENV` vars at all. In the second case you've passed in the URL (and thus can make a request and receive a response) but you've left out all the other vars which results in the server saying you've made a bad request.

The solution is either *pass in the `ENV` vars for the user running `ruby`* or *hardcode your values in your script*.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean ):
The envs are set inside my .env file

Comment: If you add `puts ENV['URL_AUTH']` into your rake task before ANYTHING else, then let the cron job run your task, and the task correctly outputs the value in the logs, then I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I'll try that right now. Still doesn't make sense, since the user running the tasks manually(me) and the one who set the cronjobs(also me) are the same, and it is working when I do it manually with a `rake` command in the terminal. I'll have your answer in 5 minutes

Comment: It's not printing anything, that's so weird. It was working a week ago, I literally just added some code to the task, and now it's not working.
Why would the cron not have access to the env variables all of sudden?

Comment: It isn't working because it's running as root. https://serverfault.com/a/247045/235711 As for why your ENV vars don't get picked up -- it's impossible to tell from the information given and that is an entirely separate question you'd have to post on SO. But the answer is that ENV vars are not being passed in, and that's why you get the specific errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using absolute file paths? I know nothing of rake but I mess up about every cronjob I schedule due to using relative file paths in the cron task and in the scripts it runs. It seems as if it's finding the rake executable, but not the script you are trying to execute.

e.g. to schedule a cron job for a python script at 12am every day using absolute file paths:

`* 0 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/file`

Also, make sure the file paths within the scripts are absolute as well (cron is not running the script from that directory).